# Wrong predictions with LSTM Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm, tensor

I am new with LSTM and I Am trying to train a model to predict the traffic flow of an IP given a year of data. The dataset is provided by Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/computer-network-traffic.

This is how the network is modeled

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2]),
               activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
```

You can find all the details in my kernel https://www.kaggle.com/asindico/computer-network-traffic-eda/

this is what I get after 10 epochs

[image]

in blu the actual values, in red the predictions.

Comment: Three things here: 1. Normalize your target using e.g. `StandardScaller` from `sklearn`. 2. Delete `relu` from the first layer of LSTM as this might actually harm training. 3. Train it longer - `LSTM` prefers longer training.

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately, there is no universal solution for that issue, but it's clear your model underfitts the data.

What can I suggest?

- Reduce the number of hidden layers in your model,
- increase number of epochs,
- change/try the optimizer function to "sgd" or "RMSprop",
- increase the batch size,
- and add regularization and dropout.

As I said, there is no universal solution, so, try something from above and it might help you.

Also, check the **activation function** for the output layer. + as was suggested normalize the input data.